# How do I use custom emojis?

Tags: c#, emoji, discord.net

I've been trying to use custom emojis in my embed messages but it didn't work

I tried using Emoji and even Emote but neither of them worked

```
var questionMark = new Emoji("<:questionmark:640216780689637390>");
await ReplyAsync($"{questionMark}");
```

If I do this it only displays the ":questionmark:" but not the emoji and I want the emoji to show up

Comment: The Discord.Net documentation has [an article specifically written for this](https://docs.stillu.cc/guides/emoji/emoji.html). Create an instance of Emote using `Emote.Parse`.

Comment: I tried using that too and I got the same result

Comment: Fairly certain it works. Try keeping the `<>`; that's the intended format that I forgot.

Answer (score 0):

Copy pasted from the [docs](https://docs.stillu.cc/api/Discord.Emote.html)

```cs
public async Task SendAndReactAsync(ISocketMessageChannel channel)
{
    var message = await channel.SendMessageAsync("I am a message.");

    // Creates a Unicode-based emoji based on the Unicode string.
    // This is effectively the same as new Emoji("").
    var heartEmoji = new Emoji("\U0001f495");
    // Reacts to the message with the Emoji.
    await message.AddReactionAsync(heartEmoji);

    // Parses a custom emote based on the provided Discord emote format.
    // Please note that this does not guarantee the existence of
    // the emote.
    var emote = Emote.Parse("<:thonkang:282745590985523200>");
    // Reacts to the message with the Emote.
    await message.AddReactionAsync(emote);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

In Emoji class, you don't need to put "<" and ">". So your code should look like this

```cs
var questionMark = new Emoji(":questionmark:640216780689637390");
await ReplyAsync($"{questionMark}");
```

Comment: The Emoji class is for standard Twemojis, not custom emoji.